# C convert signed to unsigned maintaining exact bits

Tags: c, type-conversion

**Edit:** I updated the example to be C. I am concerned specifically with C and not C++ (sorry for the confusion, see situation below).

I am looking for a safe way to convert a signed integer to an unsigned integer while always maintaining the exact same bit pattern between conversions. As I understand it, simply casting has undefined or implementation dependent behavior so it is not safe to rely on (case A below). But what about bit-wise operators like OR (case B below)? Can bit-wise OR be used to safely convert signed to unsigned? What about the reverse?

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // NOTE: assuming 32bit ints
    // example bit pattern: 11111111110001110001001111011010
    //   signed int value: -3730470
    // unsigned int value: 4291236826

    // example 1
    // signed -> unsigned
    int s1 = -3730470; 
    unsigned int u1a = (unsigned int)s1;
    unsigned int u1b = (unsigned int)0 | s1;

    printf("%u\n%u\n", u1a, u1b);

    // example 2
    // unsigned -> signed
    unsigned int u2 = 4291236826;
    int s2a = (int)u2;
    int s2b = (int)0 | u2;

    printf("%i\n%i\n", s2a, s2b);
}
```

---

**Situation:** I am writing a [PostgreSQL C-Language function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/xfunc-c.html)/extension to add popcount functionality ([my first attempt code here](https://github.com/yo1dog/pg_popcount/blob/master/popcount.c)). PostgreSQL does not support unsigned types ([ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html)). All the efficient methods of calculating popcount I found require unsigned data types to work correctly. Therefore, I must be able to convert the signed data types to an unsigned data type without changing the bit pattern.

**Off topic:** I do realize that an alternate solution would be to use PostgreSQL bit string `bit` and `varbit` data types instead of the integer data types, but for my purposes the integer data types are much easier to use and manage.

Comment: Use a `union` to maintain exact bits. "simply casting has undefined or implementation dependent behavior so it is not safe to rely on" is not so going to `unsigned`.

Comment: Code appears to be C++, but question is tagged C....

Comment: Keep in mind that the signed bit representation is implementation defined. So apparently it will behave differently on different platforms.

Comment: To add to what EugeneSh notes, if you're trying to do bit (masking) operations, use unsigned. If you're mixing signed and unsigned, you're either trying to do low-level bit manipulations for arithmetic-related code (why?), or someone is being done horribly wrong.

Comment: @JohnBollinger IIRC, C and C++ differ on how unions are accessed, so using that to "safe way to convert a signed integer to an unsigned integer while always maintaining the exact same bit pattern" diverges between languages.  IAC, focusing on one language is still recommended.

Comment: @chux IIRC in C++ accessing a non-active member of a union (not the last object to be set) is UB, ie type-punning through `union` is illegal. But in reality all compilers do what you think it will

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am interested in C, not C++. The reason I am mixing signed and unsigned is because PostgreSQL does not support unsigned data types. I am doing bit-level manipulations because I am attempting to implement one of the popcount algorithms I have found. I have updated the question with all the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a safe way to convert a signed integer to an unsigned integer while always maintaining the exact same bit pattern between conversions

A `union` will work as below even if the `int` is a rare non-2's complement.  Only on very expectational platforms (ticking away in a silicon graveyard) where `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX` will this be a problem.

```
union {
  int i;
  unsigned u;
} x = { some_int };
printf("%d\n", some_int);
printf("%u\n", x.u);
```

Yet if one can limit oneself to common 2's complement `int`, the below is sufficient.

```
unsigned u = (unsigned) some_int;
```

---

> But what about bit-wise operators like OR (case B below)?
>   Can bit-wise OR be used to safely convert signed to unsigned?

The following `|` is like a hidden cast due to *integer promotions*:

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`.  C11dr §6.3.1.1 3

```
int s1 = -3730470; 
unsigned int u1b = (unsigned int)0 | s1;
// just like
                 = (unsigned int)0 | (unsigned int)s1;
                 =                   (unsigned int)s1;
```

---

> What about the reverse?

Converting a `unsigned int` to a `signed int` is well defined if the value is representable in both `[0...INT_MAX]`.  Converting an out-of-`int`-range `unsigned` to `int` is ...

> either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. §6.3.1.3 3

Best to use unsigned types for bit manipulations.
The below code may often work as hoped, but should not be used for robust coding.

```
// NOTE: assuming 32bit ints, etc.
unsigned int u2 = 4291236826;
int s2a = (int)u2;  // avoid this
```

Alternative

```
int s2a;
if (u2 > INT_MAX) {
  // Handle with some other code
} else {
  s2a = (int) u2; // OK
}
```

---

BTW: better to append `u` to *unsigned constants* like 4291236826 to convey to the compiler that indeed an *unsigned constant* is intended and not a `long long` like 4291236826.

```
unsigned int u2 = 4291236826u;
```

Comment: Sounds like `int s1 = -3730470; unsigned int u1a = (unsigned int)s1;` will work for my purpose. Thanks!

Comment: Yes - going to unsigned types poses few difficulties.  Going to `int`, well, is best avoided.

Comment: Awesome. Actually, is the explicit cast necessary? I assume I can do `unsigned int u1a = s1;`?

Comment: @Mike "s the explicit cast necessary?" --> yes/no.  Some pedantic warnings whine without it as it can be a source of trouble, else it is OK to leave off.  Follow your group's coding guidelines concerning this.

Comment: I see that this turned out to be a C question after all; nice answer. "... where `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX`"-- this sounds rather exotic, given that `int` and `unsigned int` must have the same storage and alignment requirements; did such silicon creatures once roam free? Question: how could it be possible to have `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX`? Differing numbers of padding bits between the two types?

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes, Legendary systems would simply clear the sign bit.  IOWs another pad bit. This makes sense for the widest type such that `UINTMAX_MAX == INTMAX_MAX` for a processor that could not handle max width unsigned math without becoming a Turing machine.   I thnk you can but one on [Diagon Alley](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Diagon_Alley)

Answer (score 1):

What about ...

```
int s1 = -3730470; 
unsigned int u1 = *(unsigned int*)&s1;

unsigned int u2 = 4291236826;
int s2a = *(int*)&u2;
```